# Java ImageIcon size

Tags: java, swing

I have uploaded a picture into my GUI which displays on a JLabel. The label dimension is set only 100,100 while the picture is much bigger, so when I upload it into the label it expands.

Is there anyway to make it auto resize to the label size?

Below is the action listener for the Upload Picture JButton

```
class UploadHandler implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame2);
        file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        pathname = file.getPath();
        icon = new ImageIcon(pathname);
        lblDisPic.setIcon(icon);    
    }
}

btnUpload = new JButton("Upload Picture");
lblDisPic = new JLabel();
lblDisPic.setBorder(raisedetched);
lblDisPic.setPreferredSize(d); 

btnUpload.addActionListener(new UploadHandler());
```

Answer (score 27):

Given the example code, one approach is to resize the image to display on the `JLabel` before the `setIcon` method is called.

One way could be to change the `actionPerformed` method, so the image will be loaded from the specified file, using [`ImageIO.read`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)) method to read the image, then resizing the image before an `ImageIcon` is created.

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
```

Then, the loaded image can be resized to the dimension of the `JLabel`, using [`Image.getScaledInstance`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)).

```
Image resizedImage = 
    img.getScaledInstance(lblDisPic.getWidth(), lblDisPic.getHeight(), null);
```

Now, one could create an `ImageIcon` to use on the `JLabel`.

```
lblDisPic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resizedImage));
```

The limitation to this method is, that if the `JLabel` is resized in any way, then the image contained by the `JLabel` will not be resized. However, as the `JLabel` is going to use a scaled-down image of the original, it would mean that the amount of memory required would be reduced (if that a concern) and original image would not have to be resized every time image is being displayed, as would be the case with overriding the `paintComponent` method.

The preferred method of achieving the task at hand is going to depend on the requirements of whether the original image is going to be needed at a later time or not.

Comment: hello, yes the image is to be needed again to display the person's information.

Comment: I believe the null should be replaced with Image.SCALE_FAST (or any of its enumerated variants).

Comment: Or `Image.SCALE_SMOOTH` which tries to scale the image more smooth (Docu says: `Choose an image-scaling algorithm that gives higher priority to image smoothness than scaling speed.`)

Answer (score 7):

Sure, just override the `paintComponent` method and you can scale and paint it as you like.

```
myLabel = new JLabel (/*whatever*/) {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent (g);
        g.drawImage (myImageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth (), getHeight (), null);
    }
};
```

Source from [here](http://72.5.124.102/thread.jspa?messageID=10006559).

**EDIT**

To add to your code change:

```
lblDisPic = new JLabel();
```

To:

```
lblDidPic = new JLabel() {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent (g);
        if (icon != null) {
            g.drawImage (icon.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: sorry, i am having problem understand what a anoymous inner class does can you tell me how do i implement it?

Comment: what about my actionListener class UploadHandler?

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `paintIcon` method on the icon itself -

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(...) {

    @Override
    public void paintIcon( Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y ) {
        g.drawImage(getImage(), x, y, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), c);
    }

    @Override 
    public int getIconHeight() {
        // see below...
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        // see below...
    }

};
```

Edit -

I realized that the original size of the image is taken into account when the Label decides where to place the x, y location of the icon.  You'll need to override the getIconWidth() and getIconHeight() methods, too.

However, there's not a good way to override these to return the label size, as there's no reference to the component itself within these methods.

One approach would be to create a new class that extends `ImageIcon` and pass the component in - not a great choice because this breaks the "reusable between many components" aspects of an Icon.

Another would be to just override these methods in the inner class as above, but put a hardcoded reference to the component as an object field, or as a `final` local variable.  Again, this breaks the "reusable between many components" aspect, and seems a bit "hacky" in general, but as it is an one-off inner class, this might be permissable.

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit the image in paint then set its size accordingly in paint and then click on save and then the same size of image will come to your JAVA application.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

JFileChooser jFileChooser1=new JFileChooser();

int state = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());         
       jTextField1.setText("");

           if( state ==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null,null);
         File file = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
         s2=file.toString();
          jTextField1.setText(s2);
       jLabel1=new JLabel();
     jLabel1.setName(s2);
  jLabel1.setLocation(50,50);
  jLabel1.setSize(300,300);
    add(jLabel1);

    BufferedImage bi1;

    try
    {   
        bi1=ImageIO.read(file);
        ImageIcon icon1=new ImageIcon(bi1);
        jLabel1.setIcon(icon1);
        Image img = ImageIO.read(jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile());

        Image resizedImage = 
   img.getScaledInstance(jLabel1.getWidth(), jLabel1.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
       jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resizedImage)); 


  jLabel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED,5));


       pack();   

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
  System.out.println(e);
    }


    }
    else if(state == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                  new JFrame(), "Canceled");
    }
  pack();           

  }
```

Comment: this will show filechooser component and will set path of image in jTextField1 and display image using setIcon ..and resize the image to pedefined values....so image do not get crop and wrong.