# How to make image automatically resize in the JLabel after it is selected by the user

Tags: java, swing

Actually I want to create a car dealer application using `Java Swing`. In which I want the user to select an image of the car which he wants to sell and that image should be visible automatically in the `JLabel` in the same `JFrame`. So the user will select an image from his own device, that image might be big or small. So how to make that image resize automatically according to my `JLabel`

I tried few things but it didn't help, the image won't fit properly inside my `JLabel`.

Comment: Please, provide a [MCVE].

Comment: [How to resize JLabel ImageIcon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714045/how-to-resize-jlabel-imageicon)

Comment: [Resize a picture to fit a JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343098/resize-a-picture-to-fit-a-jlabel)

Comment: [Scale the ImageIcon automatically to label size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size)

Comment: [Java ImageIcon size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244848/java-imageicon-size)

Comment: [Resize ImageIcon](https://coderanch.com/t/331731/java/Resize-ImageIcon) (from _JavaRanch_ forums)