# How to make image automatically resize in the JLabel after being selected by the user

Tags: java, swing

Actually I want to create a car dealer application, using Java *Swing*, in which I want the user to select an image of the car which he wants to sell and that image should be visible automatically in the `JLabel` in the same `JFrame`. So the user will select an image from his own device, that image might be big or small. So how to make that image resize automatically according to my `JLabel`?

I tried few things but it didn't help, the image won't fit properly inside my `JLabel`.

```java
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class Add_car extends JFrame {
    private JLabel carno_lbl, ownername_lbl, carname_lbl, amount_lbl, imagelbl, heading, background;
    private JTextField carno_txt, ownername_txt, carname_txt, amount_txt;
    private JButton selimage_btn;

    public Add_car() {
        this.setLayout(null);

        background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:\\Sanket\\Java projects\\Car Management\\images\\lambo.jpg"));
        background.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 800);

        heading = new JLabel("***Car Dealers*** ", JLabel.CENTER);
        heading.setFont(new Font("gabriola", Font.BOLD, 30));
        heading.setBounds(470, 25, 210, 60);
        heading.setForeground(Color.RED);
        background.add(heading);

        carname_lbl = new JLabel("Model : ");
        carname_lbl.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
        carname_lbl.setFont(new Font("gabriola", Font.ITALIC, 26));
        carname_lbl.setBounds(130, 130, 150, 50);
        background.add(carname_lbl);

        carname_txt = new JTextField();
        carname_txt.setFont(new Font("", Font.ITALIC, 23));
        carname_txt.setBounds(290, 130, 350, 30);
        background.add(carname_txt);

        carno_lbl = new JLabel("Car Number :");
        carno_lbl.setFont(new Font("gabriola", Font.ITALIC, 26));
        carno_lbl.setBounds(130, 190, 150, 50);
        background.add(carno_lbl);

        carno_txt = new JTextField();
        carno_txt.setFont(new Font("gabriola", Font.ITALIC, 26));
        carno_txt.setBounds(290, 190, 350, 30);
        background.add(carno_txt);

        ownername_lbl = new JLabel("Seller name : ");
        ownername_lbl.setFont(new Font("gabriola", Font.ITALIC, 26));
        ownername_lbl.setBounds(130, 250, 150, 50);
        background.add(ownername_lbl);

        ownername_txt = new JTextField();
        ownername_txt.setFont(new Font("gabriola", Font.ITALIC, 26));
        ownername_txt.setBounds(290, 250, 350, 30);
        background.add(ownername_txt);

        amount_lbl = new JLabel("SELLING AMOUNT : ");
        amount_lbl.setFont(new Font("gabriola", Font.ITALIC, 26));
        amount_lbl.setBounds(130, 310, 150, 50);
        background.add(amount_lbl);

        amount_txt = new JTextField();
        amount_txt.setFont(new Font("gabriola", Font.ITALIC, 26));
        amount_txt.setBounds(290, 310, 350, 30);
        background.add(amount_txt);

        imagelbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(""));
        imagelbl.setBounds(680, 110, 500, 500);
        imagelbl.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        background.add(imagelbl);

        selimage_btn = new JButton("Select Image");
        selimage_btn.setBounds(850, 620, 150, 50);
        background.add(selimage_btn);
        selimage_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
                int result = jf.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        File file = jf.getSelectedFile();
                        BufferedImage picture = ImageIO.read(file);

                        imagelbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(picture));

                    }
                    catch (Exception ioe) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "selectimg:" + ioe.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        this.setContentPane(background);
        this.setSize(1200, 800);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Add_car();
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghYE0.png)

I tried few things but all of them led to many errors so I removed them, still I want to resize my image.

Comment: Use a real layout Manager instead of null layout, and change the preferred size of the jlabel

Comment: [this.setLayout(null);](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)

Comment: I would like to know why you posted the same question twice, rather than edit your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77066833/how-to-make-image-automatically-resize-in-the-jlabel-after-it-is-selected-by-the). Did the links in my comments not help?

Comment: The [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) will dynamically resize the image to fill the space available to the label

Comment: @Abra sorry i didn't actually saw ur comment before producing a new on. that link helped me